# Hide row based on parameter value

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How can I simply hide row based on selected parameter in SSRS 2012. 
I have LineGuid parameter that has two values: `Earthquake` and `Wind`

[image]

I want to hide the row if 'Wind' parameter is chosen, because it shows sum value for Earthquake.

So I am entering an Expression in `Row Visibility` but it gives me an error saying: "Overload resolution failed because no Public '=' can be called..."

[image]

[image]
I also tried to pass `Value`(GUID), not `Label` but gives me the same error.
[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by `I want to display the row only if 'Earthquake' parameter chosen`? did the rows related with `wind` showed up ?

Comment: Sorry. I edited:
I want to hide the row if 'Wind' parameter is chosen, because it shows sum value for Earthquake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the Line GUID parameter set to accept multiple values. The values are passed in as an array which is why you see the `String()` syntax in the error message. One option is to change that to not accept multiple values. Another option is to use the First selected value like so:

```
=Parameters!lineGuid.Value(0)
```

Note the reference to the array index on the end of the expression.

If you want to combine all the values you can also join them like this:

```
=Join(Parameters!lineGuid.Value, ", ")
```

This will concatenate the values in the array into a comma separated string.

Comment: This expression works: `=IIF(Parameters!lineGuid.Label(0) = "Wind", True,False)`

Comment: Thank you very mush @SteveWhite

Comment: Oh, id doesnt work if I choose both `Earthquake` and `Wind`.

Comment: Where should I insert this expression `=Join(Parameters!lineGuid.Value, ", ")`  ?

Comment: If you want to allow both options you would need to use the `Join` function to combine them and then an `InStr` to check if each value is present in the string. These can all be combined in your `IIF` statement.

Comment: Yes, I want to allow both options as well. But I am confused, I never used `InStr` function.

Comment: Are there any similar examples I can look at? Thanks

Comment: Yes, if you search for "SSRS InStr" you'll get lots of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Join all of your parameters together, then check to see if Wind is part of the string.

```
= IIF(InStr(Join(Parameters!lineGuid.Label,","),"Wind") > 0,True,False)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to display row when "`Earthquake`" parameter is chosen, and also when both parameter chosen: `Earthquake` and `Wind`.
This expression made it work:

```
    =IIF(InStr(JOIN(Parameters!lineGuid.Label,","),"E") 
OR 
InStr(JOIN(Parameters!lineGuid.Label,","),"W") 
AND 
InStr(JOIN(Parameters!lineGuid.Label,","),"E")>0,False,True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try use the actually parameter `.value` not `.label` name

Comment: I tried to do that too. Im passing GUID value, but gives me the same error. I added a picture
Thanks

Comment: seems like a conversion issue, could you paste that error page again

Comment: An error occurred during local report processing. 
The hiddedn expression for Tablix3 contains an error:  overload resolution failed because no public '=' can be called with these arguments:  'Public Shared Operator = (a As String, b As String) as Boolean': Argument matching parameter 'a' cannot convert from Object() to string

Comment: what is the data type for your `@lineGUID`?